# Forward and current iterators

Tags: iterator, rust

Is there was another way of writing this?

```
fn main() {
    let mut a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
    let mut iter1 = a.iter();
    let mut iter2 = a.iter().skip(1).peekable();

    while iter2.peek().is_some() {
        println!("iter1: {:?}, iter2: {:?}", iter1.next(), iter2.next());
    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you could use some words to describe what the code does / is supposed to do?

Comment: Just wondering if there is a way for a iterator to look ahead or look behind instead of using two iterators

Answer (score 3):

I am not certain of what is the exact question but the code itself could be rewritten using the [`windows`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.windows) iterator:

```
fn main() {
    let a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
    for w in a.windows(2) {
        println!("elem1: {:?}, elem2: {:?}", w[0], w[1]);
    }
}
```